# Setting HTML-formatted text to clipboard in Expo

Tags: html, ios, react-native, expo, clipboard

Is there a way to manually set HTML-formatted text to clipboard, so that when user pastes it from clipboard for example to mail app, the message is formatted (eg. embedded links works, paragraphs and other formatting works)?

I'm using React Native with Expo, and Clipboard.setString() sets just text to clipboard, so if I'm setting something like:

```
<html><body><p>Paragraph</p><a href="https://www.google.com">Link</a></body></html>
```

to clipboard, mail app pastes it as it, and not formatted paragraph and link. On the other hand, if I select content from web browser and paste it to mail, then it's formatted as it was on the web page.

Any workarounds?